# Jquery Uploadify not working with Codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, upload, http-status-code-404, uploadify

I have a project made in Wordpress, and in my root folder I've added a folder named revies containing Codeigniter files.

> mysite
>
> - reviews
> - the rest of wordpress folders and files

The problem is that when I try to use uploadify to upload an image (the script file is set to /reviews/upload -> upload is the controller), the page is not routed by CodeIgniter but is routed by WordPress.

The strange thing is that when I call the page mysite.com/review/upload from browser it works. But when it is called from uploadify, it returns the 404 page from Wordpress.

Uploadify

```
jQuery('#custom_file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'       : '<?=site_url("js/uploadify/uploadify.swf")?>',
    'script'         : '<?=site_url("/reviews/upload")?>',
    'cancelImg'      : '<?=site_url("js/uploadify/cancel.png")?>',
    'multi'          : true,
    'auto'           : true,
    'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
    'fileDesc'       : 'Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG)',
    'queueID'        : 'custom-queue',
    'queueSizeLimit' : 3,
    'simUploadLimit' : 3,
    'removeCompleted': false
    }
);
```

How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you posted some code. I suspect it has to do with the URL set in uploadify (the setting for `script`). Have you confirmed exactly where uploadify is posting the data?

Comment: Have you got any session control involved.  If so you'll probably hit the issue identified here - [link]http://www.uploadify.com/faqs/how-do-i-send-the-session-id-to-the-back-end-script/

Comment: I don't need the session ID. The uploadify is suppose to make the request to the /reviews/upload page (from Codeigniter), but the request is taken by the index.php from Wordpress (mysite/index.php instead of mysite/reviews/index.php

Comment: Post your .htaccess file please it is most likely a mod_rewrite issue.

Comment: My bad looks like you don't use mod_rewrite see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Change `'<?=site_url("/reviews/upload")?>'` to `'/reviews/upload'`

`site_url()` is both a wordpress and CI function.

If you are not using mod_rewrite to remove index.php it will write `<?=site_url("/reviews/upload")?>` as `mysite/index.php/reviews/upload`.